# Update composer removes some functions in my project

Tags: yii2, composer-php

When I update composer In my yii2 project some functions are being deleted in some files. For instance, function I've created in yii\web\Controller class is being deleted. What does it mean???

Comment: you should not add your functions inside vendor directory. when you update yii2 with composer, all files inside vendor directory gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend `yii\web\Controller` to your own `MyController` class in project directory (not in vendor!). Never edit files in `vendor` directory, if you need to add/edit something - extend it to your own class, for example in `frontend/models/MyExtendedModel`.

`composer update` updates all files inside `/vendor` to actual versions, depends on config in `composer.json`.